# What Plug Computer to use for a stats screen?

Tags: linux, java

For our office I'd like to build a "screen" that shows realtime statistics of an online game we developed. It'll have graphs, charts, numbers and all that stuff showing full screen, and I'd prefer to program it in Java.

As for the hardware, my idea is to get a [Plug Computer](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Plug_computer) with a video connection and connect that to an old screen we probably have lying around, which may or may not support DVI (and certainly nothing newer). I'd then install Linux on it, if it isn't already.

Can I connect a plug computer to a VGA screen? And if yes, do you have a recommendation for a specific model?

Comment: No old boxen laying around that would make this whole thing 100x easier?

Comment: Maybe, but the power usage of those is higher. Though I suspect it'll matter little in the overall consumption of the office.

Comment: I'd go the old boxen route. Think about how much energy was spent to make the boxen. People often forget that when thinking "green".

Comment: I've got a Seagate Dockstar and a Mimo displaylink screen; in theory you could use a USB DisplayLink DVI plug and do this.  The Mimo display suffers a bit from video corruption; I don't know if this is due to the driver or the display itself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also working on a similar thing and my decision has been to use a Atom D510 box roughly the size of a VHS tape, and run a regular distro on it.  The display is just a "kiosk mode" browser, which has made my life VERY easy.  I thought about using a Beagle Board, which can drive HDMI, but the time required to make that happen is likely to be dozens of hours.  This took me around an hour to get set up.  I plan to further reduce power consumption of the box itself by using PXE booting to get the hard drive out of it.  Currently I'm prototyping it on an Atom 330 system, which uses around 30W, the D510 should push that down closer to 10W.

A low power computer like the Beagle Board would cut that way down, but I'd never make up the effort to implement it in electricity savings, not even close.  That's why my calculations decided.

[I have some information, pictures, and code up in my github repos](https://github.com/linsomniac/sign1/wiki).